# .NET 4.0 - setting access permissions to file system for dll functions

Tags: c#, security, code-access-security

In my application, users can dynamically load their dll files and run functions from the dll. 
I want to prevent their code from accessing the file system (read/write to local files).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `AppDomain` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx) and the `FileIOPermission` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

take a look at this link, it will tell you what you need to know to get started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee677170.aspx